# Spring Security 5 + Spring 4 - Is this supported?

Tags: spring, spring-security

We have a need to use the new Spring Security 5 OAuth 2 libraries in one of our apps but it is using spring 4.  Do we have to upgrade the Spring Core libraries to version 5 to match the Spring Security 5 version?  Pretty certain that we have to do this, but its a non trivial effort so trying to understand if it is necessary.

Comment: [This link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#maven-without-spring-boot), states (my emphasis) "Spring Security builds against Spring Framework 5.1.9.RELEASE, but should generally work with any **newer** version of Spring Framework 5.x The problem that many users will have is that Spring Security’s transitive dependencies resolve Spring Framework 5.1.9.RELEASE which can cause strange classpath problems.".

That doesn't explicitly state that it doesn't work with older versions, but take from it what you will.

Comment: I guess the only way to find it out is to try it. AFAIK Spring doesn't ensure downward compatibility for major releases.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Moose!  That's the info I wqs looking for.